# Spring boot JUnit testing : Null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am new to JUnit and this is a sample JUnit testing implementation.  When I run the test cases I am getting a Null Pointer Exception at the below-mentioned line. I debugged the code and noticed that values passed through the test case are accessible inside the controller function and it's printing the values as expected but still, it shows Null Pointer exception.   Can someone tell me what is wrong with the implementation?

**Dtos**

```
class A{
    
         B b;
         
         //getter & setter
    
    }
    
    class B extends C{
    
         int first;
         
         //getter & setter
    
    }
    
    class C{
    
         int second;
         
         //getter & setter
    
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
class MyController{

    @Autowired
    MyService service;   

   void checkIt( A obj ){
       sysout ( obj ); // values are printed 
       service.validate( obj.getB() ) //Null pointer Exception at this line
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
class MyService {

   protected void validate(B obj){
      sysout( obj );
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
Class ValidateTest{

   private A testValues(){

      A obj=new A();
    
      B b=new B();
      b.setFirst(1);
      b.setSecond(2);

      obj.setB(b);
      return obj;
   }

   @Test
   void testIt(){
      A obj = testValues();
      MyController controller=new MyController();
      controller.checkIt(obj);    

   }
}
```

Comment: your instance isn't created using Spring injection, so your autowired won't work, you 'll need to mock that service

Comment: Use constructor injection instead of field injection, and your problem will go away.

Comment: ok ...got it..thank u